# Make a list of 10 random reals between 30 and 35

Tags: spyder

Please help if possible. I am hoping to complete this code to write a program that generates 10 random reals between 30 and 35 with square brackets around the whole group - i can only get them to change into single lists to appear, but they need to all be in the same list.
this is my current solution:

```
import random

def problem2_4():
    random.seed(70)
    ct = 0
    while ct <= 9:
        a = random.random()*5
        a = a+30
        a = [a]
        print(a,end=" ")
        ct = ct+1
```

but when you execute it it is meant to look like this:

problem2_4()

[34.54884618961936, 31.470395203793395, 32.297169396656095, 30.681793552717807,
 34.97530360173135, 30.773219981037737, 33.36969776732032, 32.990127772708405, 
 33.57311858494461, 32.052629620057274]

Comment: Please tag the question with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
a = [random.uniform(30,35) for x in range(10)]
print(a)
```